# WPF заполнение DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. Допустим имеется DataGrid который должен отображать данные из некоторой таблицы, двумерного массива, списка списков или подобной структуры. Иными словами я не знаю точно сколько в этой таблице строк и столбцов. Мне нужно просто отобразить в датагриде таблицу произвольного размера. Как я могу это сделать? Все решения что я видел предусматривали то что мне известно количество столбцов. Поробовал сделать что то такое

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyTableGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>


var resultDetails = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
    new List<int> { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }
};
PeriodicTableGrid.ItemsSource = resultDetails;
```

Но вместо содержимого таблицы я получаю вот что:

[image]

Можно ли как-то сформировать грид так чтобы он отображал содержимое таблицы в независимости от ее размерности?

Comment: @JuniorTwo: может, это поможет: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/15221279/276994>?

Comment: я могу ошибаться но вроде это не очень в стиле wpf. Что-то слышал про биндинг и тд. Ведь должны же быть какие-то простые средства заполнить таблицу, раз уж есть такой компонент как DataGrid

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Проблема вот в чём: нетипизированные строки (а у вас строки = массивы) тоже не в стиле wpf. Если бы у вас вместо `List<List<int>>` был бы `List<SomeClass>`, было бы куда проще.

А что и вправду _означают_ ваши данные? Неужели вам и правда нужен массив, а не более семантичный тип строки?

Comment: ну на самом деле мне нужен не именно массив целых чисел, мне нужна возможность отображать в виде таблицы некую информацию. Например SomeClass[][] или int[][] (тип не важен, важно понять сам принцип как отобразить данные в виде таблицы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataGrid` предназначен для отображения данных табличного типа: по существу, ему нужна последовательность экземпляров одного и того же класса. Так что вы используете его не по назначению, отсюда и проблемы.

Если вам нужно отобразить много **одинаковых** элементов, я бы посоветовал `UniformGrid` + `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FlattenedItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

и в code-behind

```
public IEnumerable<SomeClass> FlattenedItems { get; set; }

// ...

SomeClass[][] items = /*...*/;
FlattenedItems = items.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: @VladD ответил верно. Можно посмотреть еще [здесь][1]


  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/80da43cf-8eae-4aa1-8c4a-fa91d213ea98/wpf-datagrid-?forum=fordesktopru